# how to write if statements to see the single checkbox is checked or not

Tags: c#

In C#, for the first time execution the checkbox should be checked, and for second time execution still that checkbox is checked, but my motto is to uncheck the checkbox and check again.

```
string checkbox = (propose_content_checkbox.GetAttribute("checked"));
```

Comment: could you add your existing code

Comment: please show your code ([edit] your question) and tell us what exactly doesn't work as expected. Then we can help to fix it.

Comment: Please note: There are several kinds of checkboxes you could use within C# depending on the UI framework you are using (WinForms, WPF, Xamarin, ASP.Net, Uno, UWP, ...) and each of them are somehow different. We cannot answer your question without some more information about your project

Comment: @sir rufo, i can understand but how we can provide more information, it will be new to you

Comment: When you create a new project, which project type do you select? `GetAttribute` sounds web app folks.

Comment: `checkbox.GetAttribute("checked")` looks like JS. In almost every C# framework, check box have a properties name `'Checked'`. you dont have to create a new project you can right click the project > property and tell us what you see in project type and target framework

Answer (score 0):

For WPF you can use event Unchecked to select the deselected checkbox again:

```
 <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
 <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,182,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
```

C#:

```
 private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
     checkbox.IsChecked = true;
 }
```